# Machine-readable list of windows messages with types and nice names

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm hoping to find a machine-readable list of windows messages with types for wParam, lParam and the message result.  Nice names for the parameters would be a bonus.

I've spent a while searching the web but I've found nothing.

It would be fairly straightforward (if tedious) to create and parse a simple text file something like this:

```
WM_ACTIVATEAPP BOOL Activate, int ThreadId, BOOL Unprocessed
WM_CLOSE void, void, BOOL Unprocessed
WM_CREATE void, in CREATESTRUCT* CreateStruct, BOOL Cancel
```

There are a few complexities (e.g. bit-twiddling in WM_COMMAND, structures whose size depends on flags) but the vast majority of messages can be simply described and the few oddities can be handled in code.

Before I decide if I can be bothered with this, does anyone know if such a thing exists already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See message crackers in <windowsx.h>. They include message signatures in comments. Extracting the information in a format you want should be fairly easy.

PS: By the power of Vim!

nmayeggOp'ak^f(ya(gg$p'akd}

```
WM_ACTIVATE(HWND hwnd, UINT state, HWND hwndActDeact, BOOL fMinimized)
WM_ACTIVATEAPP(HWND hwnd, BOOL fActivate, DWORD dwThreadId)
WM_ASKCBFORMATNAME(HWND hwnd, int cchMax, LPTSTR rgchName)
WM_CANCELMODE(HWND hwnd)
WM_CHANGECBCHAIN(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndRemove, HWND hwndNext)
WM_CHAR(HWND hwnd, TCHAR ch, int cRepeat)
WM_CHARTOITEM(HWND hwnd, UINT ch, HWND hwndListbox, int iCaret)
WM_CHILDACTIVATE(HWND hwnd)
WM_CLEAR(HWND hwnd)
WM_CLOSE(HWND hwnd)
WM_COMMAND(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify)
WM_COMPACTING(HWND hwnd, UINT compactRatio)
WM_COMPAREITEM(HWND hwnd, const COMPAREITEMSTRUCT * lpCompareItem)
WM_CONTEXTMENU(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndContext, UINT xPos, UINT yPos)
WM_COPY(HWND hwnd)
WM_CREATE(HWND hwnd, LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc, HWND hwndChild, int type)
WM_CUT(HWND hwnd)
WM_DEADCHAR(HWND hwnd, TCHAR ch, int cRepeat)
WM_DELETEITEM(HWND hwnd, const DELETEITEMSTRUCT * lpDeleteItem)
WM_DESTROY(HWND hwnd)
WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD(HWND hwnd)
WM_DEVICECHANGE(HWND hwnd, UINT uEvent, DWORD dwEventData)
WM_DEVMODECHANGE(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR lpszDeviceName)
WM_DISPLAYCHANGE(HWND hwnd, UINT bitsPerPixel, UINT cxScreen, UINT cyScreen)
WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD(HWND hwnd)
WM_DRAWITEM(HWND hwnd, const DRAWITEMSTRUCT * lpDrawItem)
WM_DROPFILES(HWND hwnd, HDROP hdrop)
WM_ENABLE(HWND hwnd, BOOL fEnable)
WM_ENDSESSION(HWND hwnd, BOOL fEnding)
WM_ENTERIDLE(HWND hwnd, UINT source, HWND hwndSource)
WM_ERASEBKGND(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc)
WM_FONTCHANGE(HWND hwnd)
WM_GETDLGCODE(HWND hwnd, LPMSG lpmsg)
WM_GETFONT(HWND hwnd)
WM_GETMINMAXINFO(HWND hwnd, LPMINMAXINFO lpMinMaxInfo)
WM_GETTEXT(HWND hwnd, int cchTextMax, LPTSTR lpszText)
WM_GETTEXTLENGTH(HWND hwnd)
WM_HOTKEY(HWND hwnd, int idHotKey, UINT fuModifiers, UINT vk)
WM_HSCROLL(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCtl, UINT code, int pos)
WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCBViewer, UINT code, int pos)
WM_ICONERASEBKGND(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc)
WM_INITDIALOG(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
WM_INITMENU(HWND hwnd, HMENU hMenu)
WM_INITMENUPOPUP(HWND hwnd, HMENU hMenu, UINT item, BOOL fSystemMenu)
WM_KEYDOWN(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, BOOL fDown, int cRepeat, UINT flags)
WM_KEYUP(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, BOOL fDown, int cRepeat, UINT flags)
WM_KILLFOCUS(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndNewFocus)
WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_LBUTTONDOWN(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_LBUTTONUP(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_MBUTTONDOWN(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_MBUTTONUP(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT flags)
WM_MDIACTIVATE(HWND hwnd, BOOL fActive, HWND hwndActivate, HWND hwndDeactivate)
WM_MDICASCADE(HWND hwnd, UINT cmd)
WM_MDICREATE(HWND hwnd, const LPMDICREATESTRUCT lpmcs)
WM_MDIDESTROY(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndDestroy)
WM_MDIGETACTIVE(HWND hwnd)
WM_MDIICONARRANGE(HWND hwnd)
WM_MDIMAXIMIZE(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndMaximize)
WM_MDINEXT(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCur, BOOL fPrev)
WM_MDIRESTORE(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndRestore)
WM_MDISETMENU(HWND hwnd, BOOL fRefresh, HMENU hmenuFrame, HMENU hmenuWindow)
WM_MDITILE(HWND hwnd, UINT cmd)
WM_MEASUREITEM(HWND hwnd, MEASUREITEMSTRUCT * lpMeasureItem)
WM_MENUCHAR(HWND hwnd, UINT ch, UINT flags, HMENU hmenu)
WM_MENUSELECT(HWND hwnd, HMENU hmenu, int item, HMENU hmenuPopup, UINT flags)
WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndTopLevel, UINT codeHitTest, UINT msg)
WM_MOUSEMOVE(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_MOUSEWHEEL(HWND hwnd, int xPos, int yPos, int zDelta, UINT fwKeys)
WM_MOVE(HWND hwnd, int x, int y)
WM_NCACTIVATE(HWND hwnd, BOOL fActive, HWND hwndActDeact, BOOL fMinimized)
WM_NCCALCSIZE(HWND hwnd, BOOL fCalcValidRects, NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS * lpcsp)
WM_NCCREATE(HWND hwnd, LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
WM_NCDESTROY(HWND hwnd)
WM_NCHITTEST(HWND hwnd, int x, int y)
WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCLBUTTONUP(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCMBUTTONUP(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCMOUSEMOVE(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCPAINT(HWND hwnd, HRGN hrgn)
WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NCRBUTTONUP(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT codeHitTest)
WM_NEXTDLGCTL(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndSetFocus, BOOL fNext)
WM_PAINT(HWND hwnd)
WM_PAINTCLIPBOARD(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCBViewer, const LPPAINTSTRUCT lpPaintStruct)
WM_PALETTECHANGED(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndPaletteChange)
WM_PALETTEISCHANGING(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndPaletteChange)
WM_PARENTNOTIFY(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, HWND hwndChild, int idChild)
WM_PASTE(HWND hwnd)
WM_POWER(HWND hwnd, int code)
WM_QUERYDRAGICON(HWND hwnd)
WM_QUERYENDSESSION(HWND hwnd)
WM_QUERYNEWPALETTE(HWND hwnd)
WM_QUERYOPEN(HWND hwnd)
WM_QUEUESYNC(HWND hwnd)
WM_QUIT(HWND hwnd, int exitCode)
WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_RBUTTONDOWN(HWND hwnd, BOOL fDoubleClick, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags)
WM_RBUTTONUP(HWND hwnd, int x, int y, UINT flags)
WM_RENDERALLFORMATS(HWND hwnd)
WM_RENDERFORMAT(HWND hwnd, UINT fmt)
WM_SETCURSOR(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCursor, UINT codeHitTest, UINT msg)
WM_SETFOCUS(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndOldFocus)
WM_SETFONT(HWND hwndCtl, HFONT hfont, BOOL fRedraw)
WM_SETREDRAW(HWND hwnd, BOOL fRedraw)
WM_SETTEXT(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR lpszText)
WM_SHOWWINDOW(HWND hwnd, BOOL fShow, UINT status)
WM_SIZE(HWND hwnd, UINT state, int cx, int cy)
WM_SIZECLIPBOARD(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCBViewer, const LPRECT lprc)
WM_SPOOLERSTATUS(HWND hwnd, UINT status, int cJobInQueue)
WM_SYSCHAR(HWND hwnd, TCHAR ch, int cRepeat)
WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE(HWND hwnd)
WM_SYSCOMMAND(HWND hwnd, UINT cmd, int x, int y)
WM_SYSDEADCHAR(HWND hwnd, TCHAR ch, int cRepeat)
WM_SYSKEYDOWN(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, BOOL fDown, int cRepeat, UINT flags)
WM_SYSKEYUP(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, BOOL fDown, int cRepeat, UINT flags)
WM_SYSTEMERROR(HWND hwnd, int errCode)
WM_TIMECHANGE(HWND hwnd)
WM_TIMER(HWND hwnd, UINT id)
WM_UNDO(HWND hwnd)
WM_VKEYTOITEM(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, HWND hwndListbox, int iCaret)
WM_VSCROLL(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCtl, UINT code, int pos)
WM_VSCROLLCLIPBOARD(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndCBViewer, UINT code, int pos)
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED(HWND hwnd, const LPWINDOWPOS lpwpos)
WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING(HWND hwnd, LPWINDOWPOS lpwpos)
WM_WININICHANGE(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR lpszSectionName)
```

Comment: `nmayeggOp'ak^f(ya(gg$p'akd}dd` I think your keyboard is ill; it seems to have thrown up. Do you need paper towels or a mop? :)

Comment: @KenWhite It's Leviósa, not Leviosá.

Comment: That's fantastic!  I'd used windowsx.h years ago and forgotten all about it.

Comment: You will occasionally run into one of the crackers in `<windowsx.h>` that is wrong; I can't remember the specific culprits, but I know they exist after being bitten in the past. There are also a bunch of new messages that haven't made it into `<windowsx.h>`, last updated back in the days of Windows 3.1. The best resource for information is really MSDN, as always.

Comment: As Cody Gray says, the information in windowsx.h is stale and sometimes wrong, but I think it's the best I'm going to get.  Thank you.

Comment: Note to future generations: if you find this list incomplete, edit it — for the benefit of the internet.

Comment: Do you happen to know if such a thing exists for common controls? (`LVM_???`, etc.)